# Is the Forge Model Upgrader Example Deprecated?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have connected the Forge Model Upgrade example to my BIM 360 hub.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-revit-projectfamilytemplate-upgrader-sample

Currently, it does not work.

Is it possible to get it to work?

Comment: what is not working? can you please elaborate? the sample still valid.

Comment: When i selected the same source and destination folder, the upgrader sample did not work.

However, when i select different source and destination folder, the upgrader sample works.

Comment: yes, this is as expected, these upgraded files should be output to another folder. The sample only migrate to Revit 2019 as demo purpose, any other issues?

Answer (score 0):

From comments: the live version works for 2019 models (as designed), but can be modified to support other versions. Output needs to be in a different folder.